# Lebesgue Outer measure of $\mathbb{R} \times \dots \times\{a\} \times \dots \times \mathbb{R}$

Tags: lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

If $\{a\}$ is a singleton in $\mathbb{R}$, is the lebesgue outer measure of $A:=\mathbb{R} \times \dots \times\{a\} \times \dots \times \mathbb{R} \subset{\mathbb{R}}^d$ zero?

Let $\delta:=\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n+d+1}n^d}$. Then $(-n,n) \times \dots (a-\delta,a+\delta) \times \dots \times (-n,n)$ is a sequence of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}^d$ covering $A$, each of length $\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$, so $\lambda^{*}(A)\leq \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary we conclude $\lambda^{*}(A)=0$.

Is this right?

Comment: Yes the proof looks good. In fact, since $A$ is Lebesgue measurable (it is a Borel set, for example) you could also just say "Lebesgue measure" instead of Lebesgue outer measure. That $A$ is a Lebesgue null set can also be seen from the well known fact that a proper linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$ has Lebesgue measure $0$